# XRDP & XFCE apparently incompatible

Tags: 20.04, xfce, vmware, remote-desktop, xrdp

Server is Ubuntu 20.04 on VMware, installed with gnome. Installed XRDP; works great - except for complaints of lagging and sluggishness. The screen's not the usual Gnome layout though; no icons, but the apps are available via the Activities link upper left of screen.

Installed XFCE (Xubuntu), rebooted. Login screen via RDP hangs then dies - there's no option to choose which desktop, but there **is** when on the VMware console. Spent hours poring through this site and many others - nothing worked; too many rabbit holes so I restored the VM from backup.

Wondering if others had the same experience; is there something obvious I'm missing? Many of the tutorial sites just say install XRDP, then XFCE and Bob's your uncle. Not mine apparently!

Comment: *"installed with gnome"* -- you should install the version of Ubuntu that has the DE you want.  In this case, you should use Xubuntu- the official flavor of Ubuntu with Xfce.  Changing desktop environments is messy - that's why Ubuntu comes in flavors.

Answer (score 1):

@Hominid999,

Please be aware that xrdp can be used with UBuntu Gnome Desktop and can present exactly the same desktop look'n feel when connected through remote connection.

If you have performed a manual installation of xrdp, there are some post configuration actions that are required in order to provide the best user experience

To have the Ubuntu gnome desktop with dock bar presented to you, you can

**Option 1 - Manual Fix**

Try to create and populate the file ~/.xsessionrc with the following content

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Please note that the .xsessionrc file is a hidden file (located in your home directory)

This would be for a **single user**. If multiple users need to perform remote connection, each user would need to have this file created in their profile

**Option 2 - Automated install**

You can also use the **xrdp-installer script** that basically perform the installation of the software and perform some post configuration actions that would provide you the same look'n feel when remotely connected as the one you have when connected to local console

the script (current version is 1.2.1) and how to use it can be found [here](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733)

Please always check for the latest version of the script at [this location](https://www.c-nergy.be/products.html)

Hope this help Till next time See ya