# How to login to the Ubuntu (not GNOME) session on a remote server using xRDP?

Tags: 22.04, gdm, xrdp, rdp

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 running on a remote server, which I am accessing over xRDP.

When I login, it seems to load the "GNOME on X.Org" (and not the Ubuntu) session. Since I am using RDP, I cannot access the GDM login screen (because I directly login).

As a result, I am unable to change appearance settings. I am experiencing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231991/appearance-option-missing-in-gnome-control-center) issue.

How to change settings so that I can login to the Ubuntu session?

Comment: Check this http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18918
Works out of the box but you can explore the script to find the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on [another](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303884/124466) answer posted to a different question (which is about making XFCE work with XRDP).

Create the hidden file `.xsessionrc` in your home folder with the following content

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Logout and Login.