# Add items to xdrp desktop

Tags: unity, remote-desktop

I set up xdrp server on Ubuntu. However, when I log in I cannot see anything in the desktop.For example, no left side-panel for apps or no directories on the Desktop, even though the Desktop folder in my home is not empty. How could I add Desktop to this environment and also add the quick access application

[image: current]

I expect to have a desktop like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to login to the Ubuntu (not GNOME) session on a remote server using xRDP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442514/how-to-login-to-the-ubuntu-not-gnome-session-on-a-remote-server-using-xrdp)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I followed it but it is still the same